# using elif to print whether a user has visited more than 2 continents but less than 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

the program says to print a response if the user has visited more than 2 continents but less than 6

```
continents = int(input("How many continents have you visited? "))

if continents >= 2:
    print("you've visited more than 2 continents.")
elif continents <= 6:
    print("you've visited less than 6 continents.")
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Just use multiple, separate, if statements. You can chain comparisons, like `if 2 < continents < 6:`, in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`if (continents > 2) and (continents < 6)`

Answer (score 1):

```
continents = int(input("How many continents have you visited? "))

if (continents >= 2) and (continents<=6):
    print("you've visited more than 2 continents and you've visited less than 6 continents.")
```